# Improve enhanaced conversion by adding a secondary implementation method

Tags: google-ads-api

[Recommendation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mT6Q0.jpg)

Would ignoring this cause loss of data or limits on capturing data . If yes , Can someone help how to go about it .

Thanks

I have enabled enhanced conversions in my google ads already and we do not use website code to edit for secondary implementation